# binding property of one field to another in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding

```
<TextBlock  Name="currency"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

<TextBlock Margin="5,0"  Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=currency" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="22" />
```

I am using the above code for binding property of one field to another in my WP7 application.

i want to do the similar task from back-end. any suggestions??

Comment: what do you mean with similar task from back-end?

Comment: What do you want to do actually? do you mean binding name of one field to another dynamically(backend??!!)? what's the purpose of it finally?

Comment: If you want to bind one object property to another, you may look to `Dependency Property`

Comment: i want to bind a textblock from the code behind.

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{Binding SampleLink}" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="0,0,0,2" Foreground="Green"></TextBlock>

how can it be written from code-behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got my solution as: var b = new Binding{ElementName = "currency", Path = new PropertyPath("Text")}; Textblock txt = new TextBlock(); txt.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, b);

Answer (score 1):

Bindings are working in a specified data context. You can set the data context of your layout root to the page instance, then you can bind to any of your properties. (DataContext is inherited through the child FrameworkElements.) If you want your binding to update its value whenever you change your property from code, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface or use Dependency properties.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Test, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>

public class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string test;
    public string Test
    {
        get { return this.test; }
        set
        {
            this.test = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Test"));
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
        LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

This is a stupid example since you can access your TextBox any time from MainPage, this has much more sense if you are displaying model objects with DataTemplates.

(I typed this on phone, hope it compiles..)